# Batch Update Permissioned Relationships

Tags: permissions, relationships

We have a specific contact/organization relationship type that should be a permissioned relationship for the contact to edit the organizations record.  When we converted to Civi many of these contacts did not get the permissioned relationship check box checked. Is there a way to update the Permissioned Ralationship check box for this specific relationship type in bulk?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to batch update relationship via the user interface b/c relationships are reciprocal. Using the Import Contacts wizard and selecting "Update" doesn't allow you to designate a relationship as permissioned either.

If you have a programmer on hand, this type of update would be easy to do using an SQL query directly on the database:

Assumptions:

- Relationship Type ID = 4 (in my environment, this is the ID for Employee/Employer)
- Contact A = Individual
- Contact B = Organization

Query:

UPDATE `civicrm_relationship` SET `is_permission_a_b`= 1 WHERE `relationship_type_id`= 4

Alternatively, if you have sufficient permissions, you could use API Explorer as documented [HERE](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/), but this should only be done by someone who has good knowledge of the CiviCRM database structure.

Good luck!